Django - How to create One to Many relationship using default User class
I'm creating an app called Trading Journal, that allows users to login and record the results from their stock trades. Each user should have access to only their individual entries. I am adding a ForeignKey field on my Entry class, tied to Django's default User class, to do this. But I am getting this error when I try to run the /migrate command: ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'andredi15' (andredi15 is one of the usernames)
So I have two questions: 1) How do i fix this error and, 2) Should I go about this a different way? Perhaps by setting up a custom user model? Thanks!
Models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Entry(models.Model):
    ONEORB="1-Min ORB"
    FIVEORB="5-Min ORB"
    ABCD="ABCD"
    REVERSAL="Reversal"
    PROFIT="Profit"
    LOSS="Loss"
    RESULT_CHOICES = (
        (PROFIT, "Profit"),
        (LOSS, "Loss")
    )
    STRATEGY_CHOICES = (
        (ONEORB,"1-Min ORB"),
        (FIVEORB,"5-Min ORB"),
        (ABCD,"ABCD"),
        (REVERSAL,"Reversal")
    )

    entered_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    ticker=models.CharField(max_length=8, default="")
    strategy=models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=STRATEGY_CHOICES, default="ONEORB")
    result=models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=RESULT_CHOICES, default="PROFIT")
    comments=models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", null=True, blank=True) #will save to default BASE_DIR which is 'uploads'
    username = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usernames", to_field="username")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.result} {self.entered_date}"

Forms.py:
from django import forms
from .models import Entry

# Authentication modules start here
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput

# Form to create a journal entry
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Entry
        fields='__all__'

# Create / register a user
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User #default django User model
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


# Authenticate a user
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())


Views.py (still a work in progress):
from django.forms.models import BaseModelForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import EntryForm, CreateUserForm, LoginForm
from .models import Entry
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView, FormView
# Authentication models and functions
from django.contrib.auth.models import auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
#this is to ensure that even after you have your login setup, a user can't just manually type in the URL
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here. 

class EntryView(View):
  def get(self, request):
    entries = Entry.objects.all().order_by("entered_date")
    form = EntryForm()
    return render(request, "entries.html", {"form":form, "entries":entries})
  
  def post(self, request):
    form = EntryForm(request.POST, request.FILES) #must add request.FILES for uploads
    print(request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      messages.success(request, "Entry created!")
      return redirect("/")
    else:
      messages.error(request, "Please correct the errors below.")
      return render(request, "entries.html", {"form":form})
    
def SingleEntryView(request, pk):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Initialize the form with the existing Entry data
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=entry)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Set the user and save the updated data
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            # Redirect to a success page (e.g., 'index')
    else:
        # Initialize the form with the existing Entry data
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    context = {'form': form, 'entry': entry}
    return render(request, "single_entry.html", context)
  
class SingleEntryDeleteView(DeleteView): 
  template_name = "single_entry.html"
  model = Entry
  success_url = reverse_lazy("index")
  success_message = "Entry has been deleted."

  def delete(self, request):
    messages.success(self.request, "Successfully deleted.")
    return super().delete() 
  
class RegisterFormView(FormView):
   form = CreateUserForm
   template_name = "register.html"
   success_url = ""

   def form_valid(self, form):
      pass
      

This is the error message from the console when i run the migrate command:
Running migrations:
  Applying entries.0011_entry_username...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2053, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'andredi15'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Documents\Django\trading_journal\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Documents\Django\trading_journal\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 356, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 132, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 398, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 238, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 429, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1129, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 954, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2742, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2055, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'andredi15'.

When I run python manage.py migrate, I expect the Entry model to be updated with the foreign key. I also tried using "User" as the first argument for the ForeignKey, but I read that get_user_model() is the recommended way to do this rather than calling the model directly.

Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

@willeM_VanOnsem I added it as requested you can check it now

Is it possible you made a migration file with andredi15 as default= f9or the ForeigKey?

@willeM_VanOnsem Yes that was it. I had set that as the default. I went back to my migrations file and changed it to '1' as the default since it was looking for an integer. But now when I run migrate I'm getting this error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'entries_entry' with primary key '41' has an invalid foreign key: entries_entry.username_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in auth_user.username. And I have verified that '1' is the correct username for the default User.

Yes this was it. In a previous migration I assigned a ForeignKey. THanks willem
